# Using a custom variable in livecharts

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2019

I am using the LiveCharts package in a .NET framework 4.7.2 C# form. I am trying to get data from a database into a chart, but have found that LiveCharts isn't very fond of me trying to use my own variables. I have not yet found a way to link these two with eachother.

```
new StackedColumnSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> {5},
                    StackMode = StackMode.Values, 
                    DataLabels = true,
                    Fill = Brushes.DodgerBlue

                },
                new StackedColumnSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> {3},
                    StackMode = StackMode.Values,
                    DataLabels = true,
                    Fill = Brushes.LawnGreen
                },

                new StackedColumnSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<double> {1},
                StackMode = StackMode.Values,
                DataLabels = true,
                Fill = Brushes.DimGray
            },

                new StackedColumnSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<double> {1},
                StackMode = StackMode.Values,
                DataLabels = true,
                Fill = Brushes.IndianRed
            }
            };
```

I want to change the {5}, {3}, ... into a custom variable, let's say "VarDataSize". Is this possible?
I am pretty new to Visual Studio 2019, so I would appreciate a lot of explanation. If I am missing any necessary information I'll gladly add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone taught me how to do it. I had to add the following below namespace.

```
static class global
{
    public static int Var1;
    public static int Var2;
    public static int Var3;
    public static int Var4;
}
```

And then define their values in the same place as InitializeComponent(); is.

```
global.Var1 = 5;
global.Var2 = 3;
global.Var3 = 1;
global.Var4 = 1;
```

And then just change the numbers with the correct variable name.

It's fairly easy I suppose, but I din't know it and I hope it might help someone else too.